# Azure Storage account blob event subscription failure alert

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-eventgrid

I have created an event subscription in storage account for blob creation events using system topic event grid. Is there a way to track the delivery of "blob created" notifications from storage to the event grid system topic ?  I'm not asking for delivery of notifications from system topic to end point like function, queue etc.

Answer (score 0):

By following @Shweta Lodha [document](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-notified-via-azure-event-grid-whenever-azure-blob-is-updated/), you can Get Notified Via Azure Event Grid Whenever Azure Blob Is Updated.

- When creating Event Grid in **Additional features** select **Enable dead lettering** to catch any events **that are not delivered successfully to the subscribers** as shown in below image.  This will send any undelivered events to the specified storage account

[image]

- you can  track the delivery of "blob created" notifications from storage to the Event Grid system topic by  **Enable logging for the Event Grid topic** as shown in the image In the **Diagnostic logs** section turn on **Stream to an event hub** . It  will allow you to view the logs in an Azure Event Hub or export them to a storage account
  [image]
  [image]
  By following this Microsoft document, you can [view metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/monitor-event-delivery)
  [image]
  Reference [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/event-grid/system-topics.md)
- For more information like how to use Azure event grid to route blob storage to web end points follow this [document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/blob-event-quickstart-portal)
  [image]
- In  Event Grid response status codes 200,201 etc. you can track the delivery of blob created notifications from your storage account to the event grid system topic